# Mono flatMap + switchIfEmpty Combo Operator?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-reactive, spring-reactor

Is there an operator that allows to process result/success whether or not Mono is empty. For example:

```
Mono<Bar> result = sourceMono.flatMap(n -> process(n)).switchIfEmpty(process(null));
```

where:

```
Mono<Bar> process(Foo in){
Optional<Foo> foo = Optional.ofNullable(in);
...
}
```

is there a shortcut operator that allows something like below or similar?

```
Mono<Bar> result = sourceMono.shortCut(process);
```

More specifically, `mono.someOperator()` returns `Optional<Foo>` which would contain `null` when Mono is empty and have value otherwise.

I wanted to avoid to create process method as mentioned above and just have a block of code but not sure which operator can help without duplicating block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in operator to do exactly what you want.

As a workaround, you can convert the `Mono<Foo>` to a `Mono<Optional<Foo>>` that emits an empty `Optional<Foo>` rather than completing empty, and then operate on the emitted `Optional<Foo>`.

For example:

```java
Mono<Bar> result = fooMono            // Mono<Foo>
    .map(Optional::of)                // Mono<Optional<Foo>> that can complete empty
    .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty()) // Mono<Optional<Foo>> that emits an empty Optional<Foo> rather than completing empty
    .flatMap(optionalFoo -> process(optionalFoo.orElse(null)));
```

Comment: Great trick !! I could possibly combine it with transformDeffered to make a reusable function/operator....Note: I had to change Optional.empty() to Mono.just(Optional.empty()) as switchIfEmpty expects Mono (perhaps update it to make usable for others).

Comment: I would assume that's a common scenario for chaining multiple calls, not sure why an Operator was not added.

Comment: I edited the answer to use `defaultIfEmpty` (what I intended) instead of `switchIfEmpty`

Comment: we don't want to introduce anything dealing with `null` unless absolutely necessary, in order to globally discourage null in the API (since the Reactive Streams specification forbids `onNext(null)`

Answer (score 1):

As per above @phil's workaround, here is a reusable function:

```
private final <T> Mono<Optional<T>> afterSucess(Mono<T> source) {
    return source
       .map(Optional::of) //
       .defaultIfEmpty(Optional.empty());
}
```

then invoke in publisher line:

```
Foo<Bar> result = fooMono
    .transformDeferred(this::afterSucess)
    .flatMap(optionalFoo -> process(optionalFoo.orElse(null)));
```